# Mathematica 11.2 or 11.3 FrontEnd not working under Fedora 28

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, fedora

I cannot make the Mathematica notebook/front-end for versions 11.2 or 11.3 run under Fedora 28 (Wayland or Xorg).  No error messages, no hints of a problem, just nothing happens.  Worked with Wolfram and they correctly say that Fedora 28 is unsupported, however 11.1 FrontEnd works fine, and Fedora is the FUTURE of the Redhat branch (sort of).

Versions 11.2 and 11.3 run fine in a console window...no graphics but can run and calculate fine.

Does anyone have Mathematica 11.2 or 11.3 working with the FrontEnd under Fedora 28?  And did you do anything special to make that happen or did it run out-of-the-box?

Comment: This might be better asked at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com, but check their Ts and Cs before re-posting.  And don't, whatever you do, post the same question in two different SO places.